# phpMailer/mail function returns true yet mail is not being received due to Subject

Tags: email, subject

I set subject to "Your Order" while sending email.
I tried both phpMailer and php mail function and both returns true yet mail is not being received in my gmail inbox.

But after changing the subject to "Order {number}", it started receiving mails.

My problem was solved yet i don't understand why "Your Order" as a subject in mail was not working even if mail functions returns true!

Please help me to understand what was the actual issue in that?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem except my problem was with ascii characters, but it stopped sending emails.

This happens, as many people say, mail function headers are "fragile".

Comment: Maybe try to check if there are no spaces between headers tags